# Get Visual Studio to display errors in correct location in multi-line macro statement

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I primarily work in C#, but am currently writing a C++/CLI wrapper for a COM object that doesn't work nicely when talking directly from .Net.  One of our .Net objects allows logging and has a handy method for logging entry/exit in blocks of code by (mis)using `IDisposable`.  In C# this is quite handy as you can simply do:

```
using (_log.Enter("some block")) {
  //code
}
```

In C++/CLI, there's no such thing as `using`.  So my initial option would be to wrap all my blocks as:

```
IMethodBlock^ mb = _log->Enter("some block");
try {
    //code
}
finally {
    delete mb;
}
```

This is ok, but becomes tiresome.  So, I've defined some macros:

```
#define MACRO_CONCAT( x, y ) x##y
#define LogBlockImpl(var, y, z) IMethodBlock^ var = y; try {z} finally {delete var; }
#define LogBlock(y, z) LogBlockImpl(MACRO_CONCAT(MethodBlock_mb, __COUNTER__), y, z)
```

Which means I can now write this:

```
LogBlock(_log->Enter("some block"), {
  //code
})
```

This works fine and I can live with it, but if there's a mistake somewhere within the block, Visual Studio reports the error as being where the macro is called - ie right at the start of the block, which makes it tricky to identify exactly where the problem is.

Is there a way to do what I'm doing here, but allow Visual Studio to interpret what I'm attempting properly and show me where syntax errors etc are in the way it's designed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to move away from the multi-line macro, and do this in some other way.

Fortunately, since you're using `IDisposable`, there's a fix that's very on-point: Declare your variable without the handle (without the `^`), and let RAII handle things for you.

Here's the C++/CLI RAII equivalent to your C# code:

```
{
    LogEntryObject foo = _log->Enter("some block");

    // your code here

    // At the end of the block, LogEntryObject is automatically disposed.
}
```

However, this does put some additional requirements on your code:

- You have to declare your variable as the actual class name, not a parent class, and not `IDisposable`. (Interfaces require the `^`; you can't use them bare.)
- The class needs to implement a copy constructor, which is not a standard thing to implement in C#.
- When the copy constructor is called, it needs to mark the 'copied from' object as not used, so that it doesn't affect anything when it gets destroyed.

These constraints are not ideal, so I'd implement a class to encapsulate the `IDisposable` for you.

```
public ref class IDisposableHolder
{
private:
    initonly IDisposable^ held;

public:
    IDisposableHolder(IDisposable^ held) { this->held = held; }
    ~IDisposableHolder() { delete held; }
};

{
    IDisposableHolder holder(_log->Enter("some block"));

    // your code here

    // At the end of the block, IDisposableHolder is automatically disposed, 
    // and it disposes the IDisposable that it's holding.
}
```

This gives you the following benefits:

- The class that implements `IDisposable` does not need to be public.
- No temporary objects created just to be used in a copy constructor.
- This means that the logging code is now standard C#, and not tailored to C++/CLI.

Here's my test code, and the program output.

```
public ref class LogEntryObject
{
private:
    static int nextID = 0;
    int id;
public:
    LogEntryObject()
    { 
        this->id = ++nextID; 
        Debug::WriteLine("LogEntryObject.ctor({0})", id);
    }

    ~LogEntryObject() { Debug::WriteLine("LogEntryObject.Dispose({0})", id); }
    !LogEntryObject() { Debug::WriteLine("LogEntryObject.Finalize({0})", id); }

    LogEntryObject(LogEntryObject^ copyFrom)
    { 
        this->id = ++nextID; 
        Debug::WriteLine(
            "LogEntryObject.copy ctor({0} -> {1})", 
            copyFrom->id, this->id);
    }
};

public ref class Logger
{
public:
    LogEntryObject^ Enter_ConcreteType(String^ name)
    {
        Debug::WriteLine("Logger.Enter_ConcreteType(" + name + ")");
        return gcnew LogEntryObject();
    }

    IDisposable^ Enter_IDisposable(String^ name)
    {
        Debug::WriteLine("Logger.Enter(" + name + ")");
        return gcnew LogEntryObject();
    }
};

public ref class IDisposableHolder
{
private:
    initonly IDisposable^ held;

public:
    IDisposableHolder(IDisposable^ held)
    {
        this->held = held;
        Debug::WriteLine("IDisposableHolder.ctor()");
    }

    ~IDisposableHolder()
    {
        delete held;
        Debug::WriteLine("IDisposableHolder.Dispose()");
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Logger^ _log = gcnew Logger();

    {
        // error C3149: 'System::IDisposable' : cannot use this type here
        // without a top-level '^'
        // IDisposable foo = _log->Enter_IDisposable("some block");

        LogEntryObject foo = _log->Enter_ConcreteType("some block");

        Debug::WriteLine("Code inside block");
    }

    Debug::WriteLine("GC::Collect()");
    GC::Collect();
    GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC::Collect();

    Debug::WriteLine("----------------------");

    {
        IDisposableHolder holder(_log->Enter_IDisposable("some block"));

        Debug::WriteLine("Code inside block");
    }

    Debug::WriteLine("GC::Collect()");
    GC::Collect();
    GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC::Collect();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Logger.Enter_ConcreteType(some block)
LogEntryObject.ctor(1)
LogEntryObject.copy ctor(1 -> 2)
Code inside block
LogEntryObject.Dispose(2)
GC::Collect()
----------------------
Logger.Enter(some block)
LogEntryObject.ctor(3)
IDisposableHolder.ctor()
Code inside block
LogEntryObject.Dispose(3)
IDisposableHolder.Dispose()
GC::Collect()
LogEntryObject.Finalize(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, I'll certainly reread this in more detail!  I did initially try using the scoping and found that it was being disposed immediately (which in turn logs the exit from the block, so you had "enter, exit, logging within the block" rather than "enter, logging within the block, exit") since it's not referenced further within the block.  It was still directly using the IDisposable interface etc though, so having the concrete type defined may well help here.

Comment: ok got it now - this answer combined with a bit more reading of handles in c++/cli has certainly broadened my knowledge :)

Comment: I'm going from memory here, but I believe that the object would eligible for collection if it's a `^` and isn't referenced further. Without the `^`, it will stick around to the end of the block. I use this pattern all the time with synchronization objects as a replacement for the `lock` keyword from C#.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I had happening when I was initially trying to implement it.  Will go back to how I was doing it but with the additional wrapper class - thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I added `#define LogBlock(x) LogWrapper MACRO_CONCAT(MethodBlock_mb, __COUNTER__)(x);`, and am going to by convention use braces so any nested blocks are in a different scope already: `LogBlock(_log->Enter("some block")) { /*different scope in case of nested log blocks */ }` - also has the benefit of looking almost identical to the original `using` so isn't as scary to other members of the team that may see it at some point :)

Comment: Be careful to put your `LogBlock` at the beginning of a block: `{ LogBlock...`. The 'end' message will be logged when the LogBlock goes out of scope, so if you do `LogBlock { code1 } code2`, the 'end' log message will be after `code2`.

Comment: yeah I realised that after I left for home last night :)  Thanks again!